# What does Ext.Callback do in this case?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Trying to learn Sencha...

I came across the following code in a controller:

```
onViewMoreEventTap: function() {
    var me = this;
    Ext.callback(function(){
        me.getView().fireEvent('onViewMoreEventTap');
    }, me, [], 1);
}
```

What is the significance of passing an anonymous function to Ext.callback?

What does the snippet do in overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of purposes for Ext.callback:

1. to execute the function in a different scope
2. to execute the function with different arguments
3. to execute the function after a delay
4. to execute a method of a different defaultListenerScope (Ext 5)

In this case it is because the author want to execute the inline function 1ms later (purpose 3). In JavaScript, executing some code 1ms later is a kind of multitasking that is not natively supported.